# keystore path in geth command does not work

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, keystore, datadir

I've lunched Geth server and want to store data and keystores in a non-default directory. I've used this command to run Geth:

```
geth --datadir /etc/dir/ --keystore /etc/dir/keystore/
```

But when I run `geth account new` command, the new key stores in the default path `/root/.ethereum/keystore/`.

What is the problem here?